# want to load a webView from custom renderer class in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, android-webview, xamarin.forms

I have two tabs in my mainscreen ,one tab displays a map,When i click on the map pin , it opens an information window , i want to click on this window and load a webview with some url content **Without hiding the tabbar present on top of screen**  .

i am able to do this when i load webview in new activity , but it hides the tabbar at the top (material design for forms).

in iOS this was simple i did like below from custom render class

```
void OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped (object sender, MKMapViewAccessoryTappedEventArgs e) {
var temp = (uiview)this 
temp.addSubView(mywebview)
}
```

the same thing i want to achieve from android 
and i have tried something like

```
void OnInfoWindowClick (object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var customPin = GetCustomPin (e.Marker);
            if (customPin == null) {
                throw new Exception ("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (customPin.Url)) {
                var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (customPin.Url+"/app/auswahl-speisen.php");
//              var webActivity = new Intent (this.Context, typeof(WebViewFragment));
//              webActivity.PutExtra ("Shop Url",url.ToString() );
                var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
                if (inflater != null) {
                    Android.Views.View view;
                    view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.WebViewLayout, null);
                    myWebView = view.FindViewById<Android.Webkit.WebView> (Resource.Id.webview);
                    myWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    myWebView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode =false;
                    myWebView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = false;
                    myWebView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = false;
                    myWebView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                    myWebView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                    myWebView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
                    myWebView.LoadUrl (url.ToString());
                    myWebView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebClient ());
//trail first
                    var me = this.ViewGroup;
                    me.AddView (myWebView);
//trial second
//this.AddView(myWebview)
                }
            }
        }
```

In android this code doesn't do anything , it simply complies does nothing.

so i want to know , how to replace the mapview with webview or add webview on top of it .

I am quiet new to android , i am assuming that i can get away with android.views.view not to mess up with fragments